# Allow multi-select in Settings.bundle - PSMultiValueSpecifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist, settings.bundle

does anybody know a way for allow multiple items selected for a setting in Application Settings? I know PSMultiValueSpecifier, but it only allows one and only one selected value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such option exists I'm afraid. You'll either need to rethink how you display your options to your users or create a new control and show it inside your app rather than in the Settings app.